# Finding the first, last and nth row in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I was wondering if PHP has a gracefull method to find the first, last and/or nth row in a foreach loop.

I could do it using a counter as follows:

```
$i = 0;
$last = count($array)-1;
foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        // First row
    }

    if ($i == $last) {
        // Last row
    }
    $i++;
}
```

But somehow this feels like a bit of a dirty fix. Any solutions or suggestions?

#### Edit

As suggested in the comments I moved the `count($array)` outside the loop.

Comment: You can do it without `foreach`.

Comment: You could use a for-loop to make it feel less 'dirty'.  Also, your comparison for the last row condition needs to be below where you increment the `$i` variable.

Comment: @Sougata I know I can. But I want to do the loop. Knowing the first and last row is usefull when building tables using PHP.

Comment: By the way your last condition is incorrect. Should be `count($array) - 1`. There's nothing dirty about that way though

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Thank you, I was being too quick posting :)

Comment: @Peter Then I think it is all ok. Just set the conditions properly.

Comment: I would move ```count``` out of the loop into some variable. It is called each loop step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Arrays

For the first element in an array you can simply seek `$array[0];`.  Depending on the array cursor you can also use `current($array);`

For the middle of an array you can use a combination of `array_search()` and `array_keys()`.

For the end of an array you can use `end($array);` noting that this aslso moves the array cursor to the last element as well (as opposed to simply returning the value).

### Using Iterators

However ArrayIterator's may also work well in your case:

The first element is available at `ArrayIterator::current();` once constructed.  (If you're halfway through the iterator you'll need to `reset()`.)

For the n'th or a middle element you can use an undocumented `Iterator::seek($index);` method.

For the last element you can use a combination of `seek()` and `count()`.

For example:

```
$array = array('frank' => 'one',
               'susan' => 'two',
               'ahmed' => 'three');

$arrayobject = new ArrayObject($array);
$iterator = $arrayobject->getIterator();

// First:
echo $iterator->current() . PHP_EOL;

// n'th:   (taken from the documentation)
if($iterator->valid()){
    $iterator->seek(1);            // expected: two, output: two
    echo $iterator->current() . PHP_EOL;    // two
}

// last: 
$iterator->seek(count($iterator)-1);
echo $iterator->current() . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

In php we have **current** and **end** function to get first and last value of array.

```
<?php
$transport = array('foot', 'bike', 'car', 'plane');
echo $first = current($transport); // 'foot';
echo $end = end($transport); // 'plane';
?>
```

**Modified :**

Easy way without using current or end or foreach loop:

```
$last = count($transport) - 1;
echo "First : $transport[0]";
echo "</br>";
echo "Last : $transport[$last]";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $row) {

        $index = array_search($key, array_keys($array));

        if ($index  ==  0) {
            // First row
        }

        if ($index  ==  count($array) - 1) {
            // Last row
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
reset($arr);
// Get First Value From Array
echo current($arr);
// Get Last Value From Array 
echo end($arr);
```

Visit below link for details of above used functions.

reset()    :  http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php

current()  :  http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

end()      :  http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php